# How to disable renditions on AEM 6.2

Tags: aem

I am new to AEM, can anyone tell me how to disable renditions in AEM 6.2.
I have tried disabling workflows in various ways, but still I am not aware of how to check whether my rendition are disabled are not.

Answer (score 2):

In AEM if you have uploaded any asset to DAM (i.e. under **/content/dam/** node) because of the node created launcher (which you can find http://host:port/libs/cq/workflow/content/console.html launcher tab). it will trigger **DAM Update Asset** workflow model.

**For Example:** When you upload any asset into DAM  `/content/dam/geometrixx-outdoors/activities/snowboarding/flower.jpg` after completion of **DAM Update Asset** workflow the renditions will be created under `/content/dam/geometrixx-outdoors/activities/snowboarding/flower.jpg/jcr:content/renditions` folder as shown in below screenshot. 
[image: image renditions]

**If you don't want to trigger this workflow model** you can set the `/etc/workflow/launcher/config/update_asset_create` and `/etc/workflow/launcher/config/update_asset_mod` launchers configuration "**enabled**" property to **false** as shown below.
[image: launcher config]

for more understanding you can refer this article [what-happens-when-a-pdf-is-uploaded-into-cq-dam](http://cq-ops.tumblr.com/post/33794096940/what-happens-when-a-pdf-is-uploaded-into-cq-dam)

~ Hope this gives you enough idea to verify your renditions related query.